# Generate ActiveX allow prompt

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

```
function checkActiveX() {
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
          try{
            var username = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network").UserName;
            return true;
          }
          catch(e){
            return false;
          }
        }
}
```

When running the method in IE, it usually result in a confirm dialog:

```
An activex control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page javascript. Do you want to allow this interaction?
```

But on some computers i just get a javascript error, without the prompt:

```
automation server can't create object
```

And if i try go generate a new activex object, i just get the error again, no new promt. Is there any way to generate a new prompt so the user can accept activex? Or does he/she need to change security settings? An in that case, whhich ones?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Security settings must be changed on the client to enable ActiveX prompts.

Comment: "An in that case, whhich ones?"